# Split value in hashmap

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have data of the following format:

```json
[{"x": "one", y: "two,three"}, {"x": four, "y": "five,six"}]
```

I need to be able to values for `y` in each hash so that they get converted in a list delimited by the comma.

```json
[{"x": ["one"], "y": ["two", "three"]}, {"x": ["four"], "y": ["five", "six"]}]
```

Is there a way to do this in Ansible via a loop?

Comment: What format are those for you? JSON, something else? You question and your example output do not make sense `"[five,six]"` is a string while `["five","six"]` is a list. Which do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

For example, given the YAML list

```yaml
l1:
- x: one
  y: two,three
- x: four
  y: five,six
```

eq. JSON

```json
l1: [{"x": "one", "y": "two,three"}, {"x": "four", "y": "five,six"}]
```

the task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l2: "{{ l2|d([]) + [dict(_keys|zip(_vals))] }}"
      loop: "{{ l1 }}"
      vars:
        _keys: "{{ item.keys()|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ item.values()|map('split', ',')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
l2:
  - x: [one]
    y: [two, three]
  - x: [four]
    y: [five, six]
```

eq. JSON

```json
l2: [{"x": ["one"], "y": ["two", "three"]}, {"x": ["four"], "y": ["five", "six"]}]
```